# Voice inside a room and outside

Tags: waves, acoustics

I think these are small questions which I would like to ask here as they are related with sound/acoustic. Hopefully I can get some helps as I am blind with physics.

1a. Say I try singing in my dorm room. To avoid disturbing neighboring rooms, I close windows and door, or else I can (though only slightly) still hear neighbors talking on a phone. Will what I do (closing windows/doors) help reducing the sound of me singing heard by neighbors?

1b. (Related to 1a) What are other easy things I can do based on principles of physics to reduce the sound? I heard that adding more pillows in the room will help. Will it? xD

2a. I went outside and found an empty open green grass field (around 110x110 m squared). On one side of this area there is a road and place for pedestrian, but vehicles are rarely passing. If I stand in the center of the area, how much will pedestrian hear me if I sing/produce voice?

2b. (Related to 2a) This maybe is obvious, but if while being in the center of the area, there are trees (around 8 meter high) surrounding me in circle (2 meter radius). How much will that reduce the sound of me singing heard by pedestrian?

Really appreciated for addressing those points. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sound propagates in elastic mediums. So to reduce the effect you should fill your room with [plastic materials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasticity_(physics)) which are able to absorb sound.

Comment: I just heard that. We can use plastics too? Thanks. Some suggested carpet/pillow. They definitely aren't plastic, right? Which do you think are better? If it depends, how is that? I wonder what those cheap/amateur recording rooms use.

Comment: While using the word "plastic material" I meant a material that doesn't regain it's original shape after the applied force is removed. Like [putty](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putty). Pillows are good choice. You can add curtains to the windows to minimize echoes and absorb sound. If you are willing to pay then [acoustic foam](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_foam) would be a good option. Useful: [Can Silence Actually Drive You Crazy?](https://youtu.be/mXVGIb3bzHI) (A YouTube video).

Comment: Actually Acoustic Foam would be the best for any purpose of sound proofing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$A and $1$B:Sound travels the same from point A to B and from B to A. Hence if you hear them slightly when they are talking normally, you sing at the same volume will be slightly heard by them. By adding pillows or carpeting the walls, you are soundproofing your room. Some of the sound will be absorbed by the material and there will also be a reduction in echo.

$2$A and $2$B: Let us assume that you sing at an intensity of magnitude I, a person standing $d$ distance away will only perceive $1/d^2$ fraction of the original intensity. To answer the second question, a tree is a very complicated object and it will be very difficult to quantitatively calculate the reduction in loudness.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I may ask further questions, for 1A, hence will just closing doors and windows truly reduce the sound compare to opening them? For no.2, I deduce by your answer that the more the distance, the lesser they hear (in my case the fraction is 1/2500). In practice, will they hear anything at all? Like, maybe considering how much averagely a person's ears can hear sound?

Comment: 1) Definitely closing the doors and windows will help because the sound will have to travel through the walls to reach your neighbors which will dissipate a lot of the energy. 2) Again it depends on a lot of factors such as how loud you sing, how loud the surroundings are and even the direction of wind plays an important role.

Comment: To add to part 2: For every doubling of distance the "volume" (excuse the abuse of the term) will drop by roughly 6 dB. That being said in a distance of roughly speaking, 50m the level will be about 34 dB lower than what is at 1m away from you. As Sam said, whether this is audible depends on a lot of things such as the [background noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_noise), [auditory masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auditory_masking), physiology and psychology of passerby and atmospheric conditions (attenuation and diffraction) and a whole bunch of other things.

Comment: Of course, the attenuation calculated above is, most probably an underestimate of that for real conditions, but it can provide some first estimate of the order of the attenuation.

Comment: Well, if you sang in an anechoic chamber then the experimental values would closely agree with the calculations above.

Comment: Sure. I ask singers and no explanation is like in this thread! Like it xD